# Kalman filter for background/foreground separation

Tags: image-processing, kalman-filter

I use Kalman filter for background/foreground separation as discussed in ["Adaptive Background Estimation and Foreground Detection using Kalman-Filtering "](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.3730). Basically is implementing the following equations. [image]

Where S-hat is estimated pixel background intensity. I have already implemented the above equations. I see that S-hat is following/close to the input image intensity value at s(x,y,ti), that means I assume, the implementation is correct. In that case, how to extract the foreground mask?
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maths and not programming. Try asking on cross-validated, or on dsp.stackexchange

Comment: @batuman I'm trying to do something similar , have you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is answered perfectly well in the paper.

You find the map by checking if `s` and `s-hat` are close to each other. The below part of the paper has all the equations and a bit of commentary on how to choose the threshold.

[image]

Comment: Yes I did as if the s and s-hat difference is higher than the threshold, I take that pixel as foreground, if not it is background. But the foreground mask image is very noisy. I compared with MOG is using Kalman is noisier. Is there any other requirement to use Kalman?

Comment: This is getting off-topic for SO and I certainly won't implement the paper for you. No, there doesn't seem to be any other requirement to using the KF. However, the paper uses this only as an introduction and then adds their own method on to that. What do you mean exactly by "noisy" (i.e. spatial or temporal noise)? What is MOG? Also, why use this at all, is it state-of-the-art or particularly easy?

Comment: Sorry i thought you have implemented it. MOG is mixture of gaussian.

Comment: I know them as GMM, Gaussian Mixture Model.